# git clone into a branch

Tags: git

Is it possible to clone a project into a new branch ? I have already cloned the main repo and would like to clone another repo that is a fork of it into a branch. I want to be able to keep comparing the differences using git diff. How can this be done ?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can specify a new remote and then call git fetch:

```
git remote add fork git://example.com/repo.git
git fetch fork
```

You can then compare branches with

```
git diff origin/master fork/master
```